# How Do I Send A Set of Data to a Javascript Function from Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, html

I am fixing a classic ASP application for violations on Content Security Policy
the current non-compliant code has a checkbox that pre-populates the data

```
                  <TR VALIGN="middle">
                    <TD CLASS="small" COLSPAN="4" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="chkconfirm" onclick="return CopyAddress()">
                      Please check here to copy the old information from the Old Info Screen.
                    </TD>
                  </TR>
```

and so

```
<HEAD>
  <LINK REL=STYLESHEET HREF="styles.css" TYPE="text/css">
  <TITLE>The Program</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
    function CopyAddress() {
        var f = document.forms[0]

        f.txtactual_address.value = '<%= Replace(strplanned_address, "'", "\'") %>'
        f.txtactual_city.value = '<%= Replace(strplanned_city, "'", "\'") %>'
        f.txtactual_state.value = '<%= Replace(strplanned_state, "'", "\'") %>'
        f.txtactual_zip.value = '<%= Replace(strplanned_zip, "'", "\'") %>'

        return false
    }
```

I left out a lot of the fields - but there are too many to use hidden fields
I pulled out the inline script, created a .js file, added it to the HEAD

```
<HEAD>
  <LINK REL=STYLESHEET HREF="styles.css" TYPE="text/css">
  <TITLE>My Program</TITLE>
  <script language="javascript1.2" src="./scripts/global_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="javascript1.2" src="./scripts/my_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

</HEAD>
```

added an ID to the checkbox

```
                  <TR VALIGN="middle">
                    <TD CLASS="small" COLSPAN="4" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">
                      <input type="checkbox" ID="COPY_ADDRESS" name="chkconfirm" >
                      Please check here to copy the old information from the Old Info Screen.
                    </TD>
                  </TR>
```

then if the checkbox is clicked run the script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
{
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e)
    {
    let target = e.target;
        if (target == null) { alert("click target null"); }
        else
        {
            if (target.id == "COPY_ADDRESS")
            {
                CopyAddress(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the data is retrieved in classic ASP

```
Dim strplanned_address, strplanned_city, strplanned_state, strplanned_zip
     With gadoSelectCommand
        .CommandText = "prcSelOrder"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", 3, 4, 0, return_value)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@OrderID", 3, 1, 0, strCurrentId)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@for_update", 3, 1, 0, 1)
    End With
'   adoRecordSet.Open strSQL, adoConnection
    Set adoRecordSet = gadoSelectCommand.Execute
        strplanned_address = adoRecordSet("planned_address") & ""
        strplanned_city = adoRecordSet("planned_city") & ""
        strplanned_state = adoRecordSet("planned_state") & ""
        strplanned_zip = adoRecordSet("planned_zip") & ""
```

any ideas as to how to get more than an integer or single character from classic ASP into a script?

Comment: What’s the problem?  Something about only a single character appearing?  Can you clarify please?

Comment: You have a history of asking unclear questions (like this one) which go unanswered.  To improve the quality see:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)